# Solving a PDE by "Conjugating by diffeomorphism?" Why should this even work?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, analytic-geometry, diffeomorphism, foliations

Consider a real analytic manifold $(M,g_1,\mathfrak{A})$ with metric $g_1$ and real analytic foliation, $\mathfrak{A}.$ And consider $(N,g_2,\mathfrak{B})$ with analytic diffeomorphism $f:M \to N,$ for $\dim(M)=\dim(N).$ Take the foliation $\mathfrak{B}$ and $g_1$ and form the object $(O,g_1,\mathfrak{B}),$ where $O$ is a properly embedded submanifold in $M.$ Due to the embedding, $O$ inherits the induced metric $g_1.$

An example I think could work is: $M:=\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ with $g_1$ the usual Euclidean metric, and $\mathfrak{A}$ the foliation by rectangular hyperbolae, with $f$ the $\exp$ mapping. You can push the metric from $M$ onto $N:=\Bbb R^2_+/\lbrace1\rbrace$ where you have $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$ becoming $ds^2=\frac{du^2}{u^2}+\frac{dv^2}{v^2}.$ Then you can take the foliation on $N$ and embed it properly back into $M$ in a way that you preserve the foliation from $N$ and you preserve the metric from $M$ and package them both into one manifold.

The significance of this process is that it yields a solution to the heat equation (for the example I sketched) with $\mathfrak B$ serving as the particular solution. This is surprising because it's not immediately apparent why the foliation on $N$ should solve the heat equation when $g_2 \mapsto g_1$ is applied. Note that $\mathfrak{A}$ does not solve the heat equation.

In the commments it is argued that $O$ and $\mathfrak B$ are not related. Then my question becomes:

> If $O$ and $\mathfrak B$ are unrelated, then why does $\mathfrak B$ solve an important partial differential equation written in terms of the metric $g_1?$

Doesn't this imply that they are related since $\mathfrak B$ carries information about the solution to a differential equation on $O?$

Let's be a little more precise. We have the heat equation (with some additional diffusivity parameters):

$$ x u_{xx}= \mp t u_t $$

where our foliational solution is:

$$\mathfrak B=\big \lbrace e^{\pm \frac{x}{\log t}}: x>0, t\ne 1\big \rbrace $$

> Is there a concrete reason why this process (for my sketched example) works to solve this heat equation?

Comment: So your question does not make much sense. First, I suppose I must presume that $(N,g_2,\mathfrak{B})$ also reprsents a real analytic manifold with metric $g_2$ and real analytic foliation $\mathfrak{B}$. But I have no idea what $(O,g_1,\mathfrak B)$ is supposed to represent: $O$ is a submanifold of $M$ and you seem to be saying that $g_1$ is then restricted to $O$; but then what does the foliation $\mathfrak B$ on the manifold $N$ have to do with $O$ and $g_1$ in $M$?

Comment: @LeeMosher the foliation helps me integrate under each analytic curve, $\varphi_s(x)$ iindexed by real parameter $s$. i can relate the foliation to differential equations and vector fields

Comment: I think you've missed my point. $O$ and $\mathfrak B$ are not related: $O$ is a submanifold of $M$; and $\mathfrak B$ is a foliation of $N$. So for example $\mathfrak B$ may help you integrate under each analytic curve **in $N$**, but it will not help you **in $O$**. So, given that $O$ and $\mathfrak B$ are not related, what is the significance of the structure $(O,g_1,\mathfrak B)$?

Comment: @LeeMosher I have now understood your point that $O$ and $\mathfrak B$ are not related. I've added the significance to the post.

Comment: I guess my point is that if they aren't related then why should this "conjugating by difffeomorphism process" result in $\mathfrak B$ (for my provided example) solving an important parabolic partial differential equation stated in terms of the metric $g_1.$