# foliational reciprocity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, solution-verification, geometric-topology, foliations

While thinking about foliations I thought about a property that a pair of manifolds could have, which I will call "foliational reciprocity."

**Question:**

*Does there exist a pair of smooth manifolds $(M,N),$ $M\ne N$ related by an isometry $g,$ s.t. every smooth regular foliation of $M$ satisfies some differential equation on $N,$ and every smooth regular foliation of $N$ satisfies some differential equation on $M?$*

**EDIT 7/5/2023:**

---

This is an attempt to clarify the statement: "every smooth regular foliation of $M$ satisfies some differential equation on $N$."

Let me start by saying that there's a bijection between the set of foliations of $M$ and the set of differential equations that those foliations satisfy. This is due to the fact that foliations by definition satisfy differential equations. Given a foliation I can give you a differential equation whose solutions are the leaves of the foliation.

So the question asks whether there can exist a one-to-one correspondence between foliations on $N$ and the class of differential equations on $M$ which are satisfied by foliations of $M$ already. Moreover the reciprocity comes into play when I ask whether the reverse is simultaneously true i.e. whether there can exist a one-to-one correspondence between foliations on $M$ and the class of differential equations on $N$ which are satisfied by foliations of $N$ already.

---

Essentially one is taking all smooth regular foliations on $M,$ restricting to the metric of $N$ which can be obtained via the isometry $g,$ and checking whether these foliations satisfy a set of differential equations. The same process is done with foliations on $N.$

If we consider $(M,h)$ with metric $h$ and the set of foliations of $M$ then the set of foliations of $M$ satisfy a particular type of differential equations. This is the same case for $(N,j)$ with metric $j$ achieved through the isometry. And then one asks whether swapping the foliations but fixing the same metric results in each foliation satisfying a differential equation.

In this question [I showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4253770/460999) in one direction that a special foliation of $\Bbb R^2_+/\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ satisfies a heat equation on $\Bbb R^2$ with additional diffusivity parameters depending on space and time. As I wrote in that post, I achieved this by prescribing a foliation on $\Bbb R^2/\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and using the $\exp$ isometry to transport the metric and that foliation onto the manifold $\Bbb R^2_+/\lbrace 1 \rbrace.$ Then I restricted the metric back to the usual Euclidean metric and checked that the foliation indeed satisfied the heat equation I mentioned.

I only showed one direction however, not both directions. Additionally this is only one foliation there are many more possible ones on $\Bbb R^2/\lbrace 0 \rbrace.$ Of course one might need to look outside flat Euclidean space to find a pair $(M,N).$

Comment: In order to expect anyone to answer your question, it would be helpful if you were more explicit about what you mean by "Every smooth regular foliation of $M$ satisfies a differential equation on $N$".

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter sure I added a part to make it more explicit

Comment: If you downvote please at least leave a comment. Silent downvotes don't give me the opportunity to correct my understanding. Thank you

Comment: You should be more explicit about what you mean by differential equation. As it stands, your statement that there is a bijection between foliation and differential equations doesn't make sense. There can be many different kinds of differential equations that even a single geometric object may satisfy.

Comment: As an example of what @J.V.Gaiter is talking about, even for the very simplest examples, such as $M=\mathbb R^2$ and the foliation by horizontal lines, there are many differential equations defining that foliation, for example: $dy/dx=0$, or $(dy/dx)^2=0$. While this example may seem trivially obvious, I'm sure you can see that it opens the possibility of more and more complicated examples which are far from trivially obvious.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter and Lee. Okay, I see your points.  I'll make a minor adjustment then. Just consider the space of all differential equations $\mathcal D$ that the space of foliations, $\mathcal F$ on $M$ satisfy. Also consider the space of all differential equations $\mathcal G$ that the space of foliations $\mathcal H$  on $N$ satisfy. Then make the substitution $\mathcal F=\mathcal H$ and check whether every $\mathcal F$ solves a differential equation in the set $\mathcal G$ and also check whether every $\mathcal H$ solves a differential equation in the set $\mathcal D.$